# New AsyncTask being created every time I type a character into a text box

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-service

I have a Bluetooth Chat app which uses a Service, a Thread and Broadcast receivers to send and receive data through Bluetooth Socket and Streams with code through several class files.

I have a text box that shows the data being sent and received, and another textbox for sending data (Type something. Press the send button. Gets sent).

However, for some odd reason, every time I type a character into this SendTextBox, the system creates a new AsyncTask. The app already starts with a couple of AsyncTask and whenever I type, a new one is created to a maximum of 5 AsyncTasks numbered #1 thru #5.

Weird thing is, I don't use AsyncTask anywhere in my code. Nor I have any code set to run when new characters are typed into the SendTextBox.

Eventually my application gets an ANR, all 5 AsyncTasks are in "WAIT" status.

What is causing them? How do I get rid of these?

Comment: So you mean it is a `system AsyncTask`, not your `AsyncTask`?

Comment: There's no mention of system anywhere. How can I tell? http://i.imgur.com/6XEJm02.jpg